# Optimzation non-linear equation solver matlab

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, equation-solving

I essentially have a 28-parameter non-linear equation. when `f(x) = 0`, I can measure 14 parameters and I have data to generate 133 equations with the varying 14 measured parameters. I now need to find the values of the 14 unknown parameters (unconstrained) that result in the minimum residual.

I believe the MATLAB optimization toolbox (`fsolve`) should do the job. My objective function is a product of 3 transformation matrices and hence quite long and not explicitly written.

```
function fRMS= MyObjectiveFunction(xi)
syms sx sy aa bb cc ro tau omega x y z alpha beta gamma 
xi = [ sx, sy, aa, bb, cc, ro, tau, omega, x,y,z, alpha, beta, gamma];
load CalibData.mat  n1 n2 n3 n4 n5 n6 n7 n8 n9 t1 t2 t3 u v
rTp=[cos(omega)*cos(tau) cos(omega)*sin(tau)*sin(ro)-sin(omega)*cos(ro) cos(omega)*sin(tau)*cos(ro)+sin(omega)*sin(ro) aa;...
  sin(omega)*cos(tau) sin(omega)*sin(tau)*sin(ro)+cos(omega)*cos(ro) sin(omega)*sin(tau)*cos(ro)-cos(omega)*sin(ro) bb;...
  -sin(tau) cos(tau)*sin(ro) cos(tau)*cos(ro) cc;...
  0 0 0 1];

cTt=[cos(alpha)*cos(beta) cos(alpha)*sin(beta)*sin(gamma)-sin(alpha)*cos(gamma) cos(alpha)*sin  (beta)*cos(gamma)+sin(alpha)*sin(gamma) x;...
 sin(alpha)*cos(beta) sin(alpha)*sin(beta)*sin(gamma)+cos(alpha)*cos(gamma) sin(alpha)*sin(beta)*cos(gamma)-cos(alpha)*sin(gamma) y;...
 -sin(beta) cos(beta)*sin(gamma) cos(beta)*cos(gamma) z; 0 0 0 1]; % (labspace to bucket space)


for frame=1:133 % 133 frames
     tTr(:,:,frame)=[n1(frame) n2(frame) n3(frame) t1(frame); n4(frame) n5(frame) n6(frame) t2  (frame); n7(frame) n8(frame) n9(frame) t3(frame); 0 0 0 1];
    Px(:,frame)=[sx*u(frame); sy*v(frame); 0; 1];
   Cx(:,frame)= cTt*tTr(:,:,frame)*rTp*Px(:,frame);
    f(frame)= Cx(3,frame); % Z=0
end

fRMS=rms(f); % Objective function
```

When using the optimization toolbox, I get the following error. It may be as a result of how I pass a value to a symbolic variables. I would be very grateful for your help in resolving the error or offering an alternative approach to this problem.

```
  Error using mupadmex
  Error in MuPAD command: DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double array.
  If the input expression contains a symbolic variable, use the VPA function instead.
```

Many thanks!!

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory. If you look at your code, you are using symbols from the symbolic math toolbox.  The error says that you can't use symbolic variables and you have to use the `VPA` function instead.  Also, you got a typo in your code.  It should be `syms`, not `sysm`.

Comment: @rayryeng thank you for your quick response! the VPA error resolved once I corrected my syms typo. I now get "not enough inputs error". How do I combine my multiple equations to construct the objective function? Thank you!

Comment: How are you calling `fsolve`?  It seems that you are defining the inputs inside the function when they should already be specified as an input into the function.  Take the first two lines of your custom function and execute them outside of the function instead in the Command Prompt first, then run `fsolve` via: `fsolve(@MyObjectiveFunction, xi);`